# PHP string enocding issue - Extra characters appearing

Tags: php, html, utf-8, character-encoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix double-encoded UTF8 characters (in an utf-8 table)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436594/how-to-fix-double-encoded-utf8-characters-in-an-utf-8-table)

I see extra characters like â showing because of encoding issues as I found out here - 
[HTML encoding issues - "Â" character showing up instead of "&nbsp;"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461907/html-encoding-issues-character-showing-up-instead-of-nbsp)

I understand that if I set the browser meta encoding to UTF-8, these will not affect anything but I need to strip these extra characters from the database for other purposes.

For eg. :

`Text: â†‘`  should be become `Text: ↑`

But if I run it through utf8_decode it gives me `Text: �??`

For every other occurrence of the â character, it converts properly to a blank space. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to "strip" the characters, you simply need to handle your strings in the right encoding. Read [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/).

Comment: @deceze The problem is we moved from a system which did not have utf-8 encoding in the database to one which does. As a result old values have an extra character attached to them which newer values no longer do. So if i happen to compare two such records, a mismatch occurs,

Comment: Are your values in the database actually broken and they have that extra character hardcoded now, or are you simply not treating the values in their correct encoding?

Comment: @deceze, values in the database are broken.

Comment: +1 to @hakre for pointing to the solution

Comment: It looks like that it was originally UTF-8 but you then imported it as Windows-1252 into UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not shared much information in your question, but according to the sample you gave:

```
↑ (has been imported as) â†‘
```

This looks like you had already stored it as UTF-8 into the export file but while importing you told the file would be Windows-1252 encoded. It then was re-encoded a second time into UTF-8.

```
↑                                 UTF8: \xE2\x86\x91    UPWARDS ARROW (U+2191)

â  - Windows 1252     \xE2 226    UTF8: \xC3\xA2        LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX (U+00E2)
†  - Windows 1252     \x86 134    UTF8: \xE2\x80\xA0    DAGGER (U+2020)
‘  - Windows 1252     \x91 145    UTF8: \xE2\x80\x98    LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (U+2018)
```

In MySQL the name of the `Windows 1252` character set is `latin1` (cp1252 West European, [specific differences documented](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-we-sets.html)), for a full list please see [Character Sets and Collations That MySQL Supports](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-charsets.html).

That is why the solution in [the related Q&A works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11436594/367456).