# How to convert UTF8 encoding to simplified Chinese

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, pdo

I was using PDO MySQL to insert data from PHP. What I didn't know, I had to use *"SET NAMES 'utf8'"* statement before making every query.

So all the input made in Simplified Chinese before making that fix (*SET NAMES 'utf8'* command), became something like '**ä¸–å®¶**'.

I have used PHP *mb_detect_encoding* and it seems the encoding is still in UTF-8. Is there any way I can convert these data (the ones user entered before adding the fix) to readable Simplified Chinese characters?

Below are some examples:

```
(first name ; last name)

"è© æ˜Œæ˜Ž" ; "è”¡"
"ç‘©æ›¸" ; "é™³"
"åŸ¹ç†™" ; "æ¥Š"
"åŸ¹ç†™" ; "æ¥Š"
"ç«‹" ; "çŽ‹"
"å…‰å‡±" ; "é™³"
```

### SOLUTION:

As mentioned in the comment, the issue is actually double encoded utf-8, which can be fixed using below MySQL statement (Thanks to the answer provided in [How to fix double-encoded UTF8 characters (in an utf-8 table)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436594/how-to-fix-double-encoded-utf8-characters-in-an-utf-8-table))

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME
SET FIELD_NAME = CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(FIELD_NAME USING latin1) AS BINARY) USING utf8);
```

*I have updated with this answer, because there might be someone who does know know about 'double encoded utf-8'* :)

Comment: Can you provide an example of the text your pulling from the database?

Comment: @DarylGill I have added example pulled from mysql using select query.

Comment: The text that you've got there looks like double encoded UTF-8. Refer to: [How to fix double-encoded UTF8 characters (in an utf-8 table)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436594/how-to-fix-double-encoded-utf8-characters-in-an-utf-8-table) (which I've nominated this question as a duplicate of)

Comment: @duskwuff Thank you :) I didn't know it was double encoded UTF-8. The solution mentioned at the url, fixed my issue.