# Selecting strings from a column where some are utf8 encoded and others are not

Tags: mysql, utf-8

The data is the names of country subdivisions. Some have been stored as utf8 and some are not. 
example, this is how they are in my table:

```
statename

Bocas del Toro
ChiriquÃ­
CoclÃ©
Colón
Darién
Veraguas
Panamá Oeste
EmberÃ¡
Kuna Yala
Ngöbe-Buglé
```

This question/answer gets me really close to a solution:
[How to fix double-encoded UTF8 characters (in an utf-8 table)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436594/how-to-fix-double-encoded-utf8-characters-in-an-utf-8-table/38877330#38877330)

If I use:
`CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(statename USING latin1) AS BINARY) USING utf8)`:

```
statename

Bocas del Toro
Chiriquí
Coclé
Col
Dari
Veraguas
Panam
Emberá
Kuna Yala
Ng
```

the characters stored as "é" for example, just end the string.

the variation provided in that answer ,

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN CONVERT( CAST( CONVERT( statename USING latin1 ) AS BINARY ) USING utf8 ) IS NULL
        THEN statename
    ELSE CONVERT( CAST( CONVERT( statename USING latin1 ) AS BINARY ) USING utf8 )
END
FROM
```

returned the same result, though I am not even sure i implemented it correctly in this select.

I am not permitted to normalize this data in this case, so I would like to select it and get

```
Bocas del Toro
Chiriquí
Coclé
Colón
Darién
Veraguas
Panamá Oeste
Emberá
Kuna Yala
Ngöbe-Buglé
```

Will this be possible?

Comment: Are you sure the (latin) strings are not already truncated in the table?

Comment: yes, i do have access to the table and they appear like "Ngöbe-Buglé" there, as an example.

Comment: What is your server version? It seems to work in 5.7 but not in 5.6 - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2zp8NAior1JKo3HzbmYoei/0

Comment: The server version is 5.1.73  :(

Comment: Try to change the sql_mode before you execute your statement: `set session sql_mode = concat('STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,', @@sql_mode);`

Comment: This worked perfectly.

Comment: OK, maybe you fixed it today.  But until you are consistent on the input _and_ change the column to be utf8, you may continue to get Mojibake or truncation.

Comment: I believe I understand what you're saying, Mr James, but like I said I'm not permitted to edit the data or the table structure in any way. It's not mine to tinker with I'm afraid. I greatly appreciate the assistance, it was very practical and helpful. I will get a lot of use out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the `SQL_MODE`. In order the conversion to fail and return `NULL` - `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` mode must be set. You can set it with

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = CONCAT('STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,', @@sql_mode);
```

If you don't want to break other "working" queries in the same session, you should reset it after you've got the resutls:

```
SET @old_sql_mode = @@sql_mode;
SET SESSION sql_mode = CONCAT('STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,', @@sql_mode);

SELECT COALESCE(
  CONVERT( CAST( CONVERT( statename USING latin1 ) AS BINARY ) USING utf8 ), statename
) as statename
FROM yourTable;

SET SESSION sql_mode = @old_sql_mode;
```

[DB Fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qBDqLVmAakwtRKPemJkuiV/0)

Note: I have changed your query a bit to use `COALESCE()` instead of the `CASE` statement, so you don't need to duplicate the conversion code.